# Android: Button action close, opens previous activity

Tags: android, android-navigation

My menu has a game button and a close button the close button closes the app but if I run the game and proceed to the results activity, and return to the main menu via the back button. The close button the opens the results activity.

Results Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(EndGame.this, Main.class));
}
```

Main Menu Button Close

```
buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Closes the APP
            Main.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: its because your `EndGame` Activity is still in the back Stack

Comment: How do I go about closing that?

Comment: call `finish()` in your `onBackPressed()` too.

Comment: I never realise you had do finish() the activity. I am relatively new to this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(EndGame.this, Main.class));
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(EndGame.this, Main.class));
}
```